# Uploaded images to AWS S3 not pushing to edge servers

Tags: java, amazon-s3, fileutils

I have a mapped local drive (X:) that points to an S3 bucket.

I'm using the following code to push uploaded images to it.

```
  public void copyData( MultipartFile file, String dest ) throws RecoverableFileApiException {
    try {
      String path = FilenameUtils.getFullPath( dest );
      File fileDir = new File( path );
      String fileName = FilenameUtils.getName( dest );
      File outFile = new File( fileDir, fileName );

      if ( !fileDir.exists() ) {
        FileUtils.forceMkdir( fileDir );
      }

      file.transferTo(outFile);
      FileUtils.touch( outFile );
      //fileDir.setLastModified( System.currentTimeMillis() );
    }
    catch ( IOException e ) {
      throw new RecoverableFileApiException( log, "There was a problem copying data file to " + dest, e, FILE_UNABLE_TO_COPY_FILE );
    }
  }
```

It creates the relevant directory (X:\uploads\category1)and put files into it on the first file upload. The file image is served correctly (Viewable from browser).

When I add new images, they are put into the same directory (X:\uploads\category1), and the image goes in ok also.
But it appears that the image is not been pushed to the edge servers.
When I view it via browser, it downloads the images instead of displaying.
In Chrome networks tab I can see it is been served as 'binary/octet-steam' content type with 0 content-length.

It's as if the aws folders need a kick at the directory level to get them to pick up the new file added to directory?
When I do the same by manually copy/paste images into directories, it servers them fine.

Use of AWS API's off the table for the moment, unless it's not possible to get working without them of course.

Comment: Have you tried this 
 (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/transfer/TransferManager.html)

Comment: What do you mean by "mapped local drive (X:) that points to an S3 bucket"? How is X: associated with S3?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Using TNTDrive to map a a removable drive to the S3 bucket. https://tntdrive.com/

Comment: Well, it sounds like your issue is with TNTDrive then. Amazon S3 is an object storage system that should be access via APIs. It is not recommended to 'mount' S3 as a file system, especially for production usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will implement at later stage using API's, as suggested by John.

For now, got it working by:
 - Creating file on local drive with temp name
 - Copy the file to mapped drive
 - Rename the file on mapped drive to proper name.
 - Done, gets pushed to edge servers.

Renaming the file on mapped drive (S3 bucket) forces the new image to be served when somebody requests it next.

```
public void copyDataToCDN( InputStream is, String dest ) throws RecoverableFileApiException {
    FileOutputStream os = null;
    File tmpLocalFile = null;
    try {
      String path = FilenameUtils.getFullPath( dest );
      File fileDir = new File( path );
      String fileName = FilenameUtils.getName( dest );
      File outFile = new File( fileDir, fileName );

      if ( !fileDir.exists() ) {
        FileUtils.forceMkdir( fileDir );
      }

      if ( outFile.exists() ) {
        outFile.delete();
      }

      // Temporarily copy to local file system
      String tmpLocalDir = System.getProperty( "java.io.tmpdir" );
      String tmpDest = tmpLocalDir + "temp_" + fileName;
      String tmpPath = FilenameUtils.getFullPath( tmpDest );
      File tmpFileDir = new File( tmpPath );
      String tmpFileName = FilenameUtils.getName( tmpDest );
      tmpLocalFile = new File( tmpFileDir, tmpFileName );
      os = new FileOutputStream( tmpLocalFile );
      IOUtils.copy( is, os );

      // Copy temp file to Mapped CDN Drive 
      String tmpCDNFileName = "temp_" + fileName;
      File tmpCDNFile = new File( fileDir, tmpCDNFileName );
      FileUtils.copyFile( tmpLocalFile, tmpCDNFile );

      // Rename temp file on Mapped CDN Drives
      File finalCDNFile = new File( fileDir, fileName );
      tmpCDNFile.renameTo( finalCDNFile );
    }
    catch ( IOException e ) {
      throw new RecoverableFileApiException( log, "There was a problem copying data file to " + dest, e, FILE_UNABLE_TO_COPY_FILE );
    }
    finally {
      IOUtils.closeQuietly( is );
      IOUtils.closeQuietly( os );
      if ( tmpLocalFile != null ) {
        tmpLocalFile.delete();
      }
    }
  }
```